# find the next unused number in a mysql database column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to work out a way to get the next unused number in a column.

I have a list of varchars like this

> `550555 001010 777777`

and i would like to find the next available number above 100000, so in this case 100001.

What would be a quick mysql command to find this?

I can get a good result with the following code

```
select (cast(pad_number as unsigned)+1 as result
from tbl t
where not exists (select 1 from tbl t1 
                  where cast(t.pad_number as unsigned)=cast(t1.pad_number as unsigned)+1)
and cast(pad_number as unsigned) >=100000 and cast(pad_number as unsigned) < 999999
order by 1
limit 1
```

but it takes 11 seconds to bring back a result. is there a way to make it stop when it finds the first result?

Comment: This sounds like a potential XY Problem.  What's the use case for finding this number, and is that use case not satisfied by an auto-increment column simply producing *an* unused number?

Comment: Can you share your data as a table? Is it a space-separated value or a set of rows?

Comment: It's not clear how you get 100001 from '550555 001010 777777'.

Comment: @David the column isn't the primary key in this case. its a reference number for a company and the numbers aren't usually incremented that way (in this case). I'm using selenium to create new entries in the table, and want values that aren't in that column.

Comment: @lemon the data didn't come out as i wanted - each of those values are a separate row in a column

Comment: @BillKarwin I mentioned in my original question " i would like to find the next available number above 100000, so in this case 100001.". I'm using this data to create data in selenium and the front end I'm working with doesn't accept values under 100000. the data that is lower than that has been injected into the table.

Answer (score 0):

if you have control over the code that adds any new records, you could just start a second table with an auto-incrementing field that starts at 100,000, then grab new ids from that table by adding records to it.

Comment: I have thought of a separate table, but there are values above 100000 that are already in use. For example used numbers might be 100556, 100596, 100606 etc. I was hoping there was a way or order the table in ascending order, set a minimum search value of 100000, then increment +1 until a value is not encountered, then grab that number so it can be used elsewhere

Comment: @thegoatboy filling in the gaps is going to be bad performance wise, unless you cache all those available "gap" ids somewhere in a separate table. like make a table of available ids, then fill that table with all the available gaps, then when you create a new record you just pull the lowest available id from that table. but once you run out of gaps you'd have to change the way you generate ids. probably better to just find the highest id, and start there with a new autoincrement that you keep somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use information from another table to find numbers that are missing in a particular table by using a LEFT JOIN. If you don't have that table, you can use a special 'seq' table where you specify the starting and ending values you want.

For instance, if you're dealing with numbers from 1 to 999999, you'd refer to the 'seq_1_to_999999' table.

Here's how it works: you connect two tables using a LEFT JOIN and then look for values that don't exist in the other column. Finally, you pick the smallest value.

So, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT min(t2.tmp_pad_number) as result 
FROM 
(
    SELECT LPAD(CONVERT(SUBSTRING(seq, 1), UNSIGNED), 6, '0') as tmp_pad_number 
    FROM 
    seq_1_to_999999
) t2 
LEFT JOIN tbl ON tbl.pad_number=t2.tmp_pad_number
WHERE 
tbl.another_column is NULL AND t2.tmp_pad_number >= 100000
```

Or, even better, instead of using the MIN() function, you can simply use 'LIMIT 1' as you did:

```
SELECT t2.tmp_pad_number as result 
FROM 
(
    SELECT LPAD(CONVERT(SUBSTRING(seq, 1), UNSIGNED), 6, '0') as tmp_pad_number 
    FROM 
    seq_1_to_999999
) t2 
LEFT JOIN tbl ON tbl.pad_number=t2.tmp_pad_number
WHERE 
tbl.another_column is NULL AND t2.tmp_pad_number >= 100000 
LIMIT 1
```